# Does Java support BufferedImage with >8 bit depth? (Deep color)

Tags: java, bufferedimage, bit-depth

I'm averaging a few hundred images, and rounding errors makes it into grayish muddled mess.  If I could use BufferedImages that had >8 bits per channel, I bet that rounding wouldn't hurt me as much.

Is there a way to use the BufferedImage code on an underlying image that is a high bit depth image?  I mean >16m colors, >24bit, which is I believe called ["Deep Color"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth#Deep_color_(30/36/48-bit)).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. :-)

There's no `BufferedImage.TYPE_*` for deep color though, so you have to create it in a slightly more verbose way than "usual". Also, as the resulting type will be `TYPE_CUSTOM` it is likely to be significantly slower to paint and display. But if you use it only as a temporary "work" image, this is probably not a major concern.

An example:

```
private BufferedImage create48BitRGBImage(int width, int height) {
    int precision = 16; // You could in theory use less than the full 16 bits/component (ie. 12 bits/component)
    ColorSpace colorSpace = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB);
    ColorModel colorModel = new ComponentColorModel(colorSpace, new int[] {precision, precision, precision}, false, false, Transparency.OPAQUE, DataBuffer.TYPE_USHORT);
    return new BufferedImage(colorModel, colorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(width, height), colorModel.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
}
```

If you want 64 bit ARGB, change the `colorModel` like this:

```
new ComponentColorModel(colorSpace, new int[] {precision, precision, precision, precision}, true, false, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT, DataBuffer.TYPE_USHORT);
```

Comment: I tried above code. it created 16 bit Image not 64 bit. Please share snippet if you have.

Comment: @PushpakJain The above code creates images with 16 bits per sample. That is 48 bits per pixel for RGB, 64 bits per pixel for ARGB. The math is straightforward. If that’s not what you want/need, please ask a different question.

Comment: This is beautiful, thanks!